# Continued development of WindowsForms code developed using .net frameworks in .net core program of WPF framework

Tags: wpf, winforms, .net-core, .net-framework-version, zedgraph

The method of drawing the CIE chromaticity diagram in the old project was developed based on ZedGraph, but unfortunately ZedGraph only supports WinFroms (.NET Framework 4.7) and has stopped updating. It seems that references are not supported on WPF either.

(And some guys recommand to use WindowsFormsHost but it only for .Net Framework project,not available in .Net Core project)

I don't know if there is any way to inherit the old code and continue to develop in the .Net Core WPF project? The old code also contains the data of the Planck trajectory, which is a good thing.

How to reference ZedGraph.winforms project in .Net Core WPF?
Or a new code that adapts to .Net Core?

Comment: The old code of the project is placed at https://github.com/MatinxHT/CIEChromaticityDiagramDrawing

Comment: What about using `WindowsFormsHost`?

Comment: after trying WindowsFormsHost I Found that WindowsFormsHost only support .Net Framework Project, do not support my .Net Core Project.

Comment: It might not be worth attempting to write a WPF control for ZedGraph. Quickly looking at the code, it mostly consists of fills and curves. You could always spend an afternoon trying to get it to work with a WPF canvas, it could be less difficult than you think it might be. I'd give it a try.

Comment: @aybe The reason why I want to use ZedGraph is that the drawing function provided by this library is very complete, and the rich-featured right-click menu provides functions such as saving and zooming. Maybe OxyPlot is more suitable in today's third-party libraries?

Comment: Yes, it might be more productive trying to use another library than reinventing the whole wheel for ZedGraph.

Comment: @aybe Hello there.I've already used OxyPlot to Show CIE Graph.Thanks for ur help.

Comment: Great job, well done :)